# ¿Como puedo retornar el resultado de mi consulta mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola estoy tratando de obtener el resultado de un count en mysql, sin embargo actualmente me esta devolviendo siempre 1, y el count lo probe en el mysql y me devuelve es 4, ese 4 que devuelve es el que necesito, qué podría hacer?

Comparto el código de la función que utilizo:

```
public function countInsumos($id_local){

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id_insumo) AS count FROM insumos WHERE id_local = ? AND estado = 'A'");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id_local);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    return $num_rows;
}
```

Este código siempre me retorna solo 1 y quiero es el resultado :(
Espero puedan ayudarme gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En su fragmento de código, está haciendo ambas cosas:

- contando filas en la base de datos (SQL)
- contando el número de resultados devueltos por la consulta (PHP)

Como la consulta solo devuelve un resultado, su función devuelve 1.

No debe contar su número de resultados en PHP.

```
public function countInsumos($id_local) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id_insumo) AS count FROM insumos WHERE id_local = ? AND estado = 'A'");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id_local);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($count);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Gracias funciono bien :)